# Not able to validate cy.url().should('be.equal', '<givenURL>');

Tags: url, cypress

Sample code-

```js
describe('My Second Test Suite', function() {
it('My FirstTest case',function() {
 cy.visit('https://www.google.com')
 cy.url().should('be.equal', 'https://www.google.com');  
})
})
```

> Error-
> assertexpected https://www.google.com/ to equal **https://www.google.com**
> AssertionError
> Timed out retrying after 4000ms: expected 'https://www.google.com/' to equal 'https://www.google.com'

I am trying to assert for the current url equal to given url.

Comment: One has a trailing `/` the other doesn't that's why your assert is failing

Answer (score 6):

It's just a typo - add the last backslash and the test passes

```js
it('My FirstTest case', function () {
  cy.visit('https://www.google.com')
  cy.url()
    .should('be.equal', 'https://www.google.com/')   // passes with correct string!
})
```

Comment: the issue was even we dont pass / in cy.visit , google somehow adding the / at the end when open the google page. in that case the cy.visit url is not equal to ci.url. Thanks for your help. after adding in cy.visit the issue resolved.

Comment: Yeah, it's not really a valid issue, the fact that Cypress is adding the trailing slash for you.